# How to access attribute literal value in directive in angular 1.5?

Tags: angularjs

I want to access the full value of title in my directive.
The title in directive should show as "Hi from Sample".
Right now it's "Hi from". 
can someone also explains why it's happening ?

**angular code**

```
angular.module('docsTransclusionExample', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'Sample';
}])
.directive('myDialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    template: '<div>'+attr.title'</div>',
    link: function(scope,title) {
      scope.title = attr.title;
    }
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<my-dialog title="Hi from {{title}}"><h2>Hello</h2>
</my-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm posting the answer for anyone facing the same issue.

I assigned the value in a watcher inside my link function.

```
scope.$watch('somevalue', function(value){
   if(value == true){
     scope.title = attrs.title;
   }
});
```

Note: somevalue can be any variable which changes. For me it's a value in the model.